# How to display all columns except the primary key in a listbox in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to display all the columns column names except the PRIMARY KEY in a listbox in C#. How do I do that?

The code that I have tried till now is:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
  string cmdstr = @"select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "' and column_type <> 'PRI'";
  string conStr = @"Data Source=INPDDBA027\NGEP;Initial Catalog=Dev_Server;Integrated Security=True";
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, conStr);
  sda.Fill(dt);
  listBox2.DataSource = dt;
  listBox2.DisplayMember = "Column_Name";
}
```

The above code gives me the following error:

```
Invalid column name 'column_type'.
```

Please Help. I am using MS-SQL for the same.

Comment: column_type is not a column in information_schema.columns.  That is why Sql is returning that error message.

Comment: umm..okay. then what would be the appropriate query for the same?

Comment: Would you want to exclude Foreign Keys as well?

Comment: Yes @DerekTomes , would be better

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to get Columns other than Primary Key ( **Not tested thoroughly please test before using** )

```
 SELECT  C.ORDINAL_POSITION, C.TABLE_NAME , C.COLUMN_NAME from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C LEFT OUTER JOIN     
(   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col   INNER JOIN 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab ON      Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
) ON C.COLUMN_NAME = Col.COLUMN_NAME AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
WHERE Tab.CONSTRAINT_NAME IS NULL
AND C.TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' -- Table name goes here
AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' -- Change this to your schema if your table resides on a different schema
```